# Why does Chrome rate a data url as cross origin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, cross-domain

I'm trying to access the DOM of a SVG (embedded via the embed tag and a data-url) using javascript from the parent window. However Chrome rates the data-url as cross-origin. Any idea why and how to prevent this? Unfortunately I have no control of the server side to set any cross-origin flags or similar.

Thank you,

Andreas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myembed");
c.onload = function() {
 var s = c.getSVGDocument();
 alert(s.tagName);
}
```

```html
<embed id="myembed" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20width%3D%22100px%22%20height%3D%22100px%22%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20style%3D%22stroke%3A%23ff0000%3B%20fill%3A%20%230000ff%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
```

Comment: Why use embed here ? embed is meant for plugins or external applications so it makes sense to consider it as foreign.

Comment: Dear Denys, that's a longer story. The main driver for tryining to use embed was to separate the DOMs of multiple SVGs embedded in one page. In case the SVGs use e.g. same class names with different styles they interfere. I know that there are other options. It was just a question of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case Chrome is just conforming to [the following requirement in the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#origin:document-4):

> If the `Document` was generated from a `data:` URL
>     A unique **opaque origin** assigned when the `Document` is created.

Which follows from the fact the `embed` element creates an SVG Document in the DOM:

[image: svg document in DOM created by embed element with data: URL]

And if you check the properties of that SVG document, you’ll see that its `origin` is serialized as `null` ([it’s actually a unique origin internally, but just gets serialized as `null`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-origin-opaque).)

Comment: Dear sideshowbarker,

thank you for explaining the background which was my question. In case you have an idea to circumvent the problem please let me know.

Thank you, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You can use blobURL instead of dataURL. blobURL has no cross-origin issue currently. I tested in Chrome 56.0

see [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [objectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

html:

```
<embed id="myembed" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
```

js:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/></svg>'], {type : 'image/svg+xml'}));

var c = document.getElementById("myembed");
c.setAttribute('src', url);
c.onload = function() {
    var s = c.getSVGDocument();
    alert(s.tagName);
};
```

Comment: The `blob:` URLs simply inherit the origin of the parent document. All the the usual origin rules work normally according to that inherited origin.